# Print a string using putch with pointers in C

Tags: c

So I'm trying to print an inputted string using putch and a little bit of pointers.

Here is my current code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printer(char *c);
char *c;
char ch;
main(){
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%s",&ch);
  c = &ch;
  printer(c);
  getch();
}


void printer(char *c){
  int x;
  for(x=0;x<strlen(c);x++){
     putch(*c);
  }
}
```

The problem is that i can only print the first character of the string, also for some reason strlen always return 3 for strings that are 3 characters and below.

Do I have to use array for this so that I can use putch since it is limited to only 1 character output.

Comment: @Rajesh yeah i got that, didn't knew i can increment the pointer, was thinking of arrays as a solution though. thank you :)

Comment: sorry for previous comment.

Comment: you define a char ch which means single char memory so single char is present any way and as it is in global strlen(c) must be 1. so printing only once.

Comment: Btw, are you intentionally overwriting unknown memory? You're declaring `char ch;` as a single byte but you're writing a string into it that could be anything. `scanf` is unsafe and WON'T CHECK for you, so you should at least declare it as an array `char ch[200];` so that you can have strings up to 199 characters long.

Comment: @nonsensical true i was just testing it and didn't really think of the memory allocations. will add it up. thank you

Comment: @magicianIam I have to say I liked the way you asked the question. You're genuinely trying to learn C which is commendable and you gave us indented code that you tried. This is good. Try reading up on C strings some more.

Comment: @PP. thank you, i'm more of a web developer that's why i cant really comprehend that much in the need of c for memory allocation and different ways of retrieving strings. thank you for your help again, I do plan on learning more about pointers since they seem to be really tricky to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the problems is that your printer() function is not printing anything other than the first character. There are two ways of approaching this. Using pointers:

```
void printer(char const *c){
    while ( *c != '\0' ) {
        putch(*c);
        c++;
    }
}
```

And using pointer arithmetic:

```
void printer(char const *c) {
    int x;
    for ( x=0; x < strlen(c); x++ ) {
        putch( *(c + x) );
    }
}
```

The *biggest* problem is that you are attempting to store a string in a single character in memory. That's just asking for problems.

```
char ch;
scanf("%s",&ch); // NO NO NO NO NO
```

Instead declare your buffer (to store the string in) as an array big enough for the biggest string you expect:

```
char ch[512];
scanf("%s", ch);
```

Comment: short and efficient. thanks for this. though would it be possible for you to tell me what was wrong in my code or logic. thank you

Comment: @magicianIam it is simple - you weren't changing what character you were printing. If you'd simply changed your `putch(*c)` to `putch(*(c+x))` it would have worked. Oh, and your array should have been declared `char ch[256];` or similar. You're trying to put a string (an array of many characters) into a character variable.

Comment: regarding the issue with the strlen that it will always return 3, did i do something wrong for that to happen? also thank you for that explanation :)

Comment: `*(c + x)` is equivalent to `c[x]` (or `x[c]`, but that is confusing, so don't do that).

Comment: @magicianIam you need to understand that, in C, **all** strings are *character arrays* where the *last character* is `\0`. You cannot do a `strlen` on a character. This is illegal. Because `strlen` can only operate on a character *array* that ends with a `\0` character.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printer(char *c);
char *c;
char buffer[1000];// use as a buffer
void main(){
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%s",buffer);//read the input to the buffer
  c=(char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);//alloc memory with len of input + 1 byte to "\0"(end of string)
  strcpy(c,buffer);//copy the input from the buffer to the new memory
  printer(c);
  getch();
  free(c);//free the memeory
}

  void printer(char *c)
  {
     int x;
     for(x=0;x<strlen(c);x++){//move the index string pointer to next char in the string
       putch(c[x]);//print the char to the screen
      }
  }
```

1)You cant use char to save a string u need char*!!!

2)You can get input to memory that not allocated!!!! because of that u must read the input to buffer after that alloc string by size of the input inside the buffer!

Comment: I like your answer but could you please add an explanation about the parts of the code that you fixed? If you don't want to, would you mind if I did?

Comment: Also need to update the printer() function to update the character printed by the `putch` function on each invocation.

Comment: @PP No need i use it as array of chars!

Comment: why do we need to copy the buffer to the new memory?

Comment: @magicianIam In fact in your example you not must do this, but if you need to get many string u need temp memory to save the input because any input have different size.

Comment: @OneManCrew i see thank you, but is it possible to print if a space is present in a string? also this only prints the first character of the string.

Comment: @magicianlam use  gets(buffer); please mark my answer with V if that help you

Answer (score 1):

First off, you pass a pointer to "storage for one character" to `scanf`. Anything that happens after that is in [nsal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) territory.

Second, `scanf` does not allocate storage for your input, so even if you'd passed `c` instead of `&ch`, you would not be any better off.

Third, you really should be declaring your variables inside `main` rather than using global variables.

Something like this may be closer to what you actually want:

```
void output (char *c)
{
   char *cp;
   for (cp = c; *cp; cp++) {
     putch(*cp);
   }
}

int main (void)
{
  char input[80];
  printf("Please input a string: ");
  scanf("%s\n", input);
  output(input);
}
```

Comment: i get declaration error at char input[80]. would you mind explaining to me the flow of this one? thank you :)

Comment: @magicianIam  I can't see any obvious reason why you should be getting a declaration error there, unless I have missed a brace or semi-colon somewhere (no, I have not test-compiled this code, i don't seem to have a compiler handy).

Answer (score 0):

Your code print only first character because c is always pointing to first character of the array. For printing total string you need to increment character pointer as well
You need to do like this

```
void printer(char *c){
 while(*c != '\0'){
    putch(*c);
    c++;
  }
}
```

Comment: You do know that the result of `strlen(c)` changes on every loop because you're incrementing the pointer `c`? If your string length was, for example, 10, then when `x`=5 `c` will point to the 6th character and `strlen()` will return 5 and the loop test will fail. You'll never print more than half the string using your solution.

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the length of the string & then use above implementation like this-

```
void printer(char *c){
  int i, length;
  length=strlen(c)
 for(i=0;i<lenth;i++,c++){
    putch(*c);
  }
}
```

It should work I think.

Answer (score -1):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

void printer(char *c);
char *c;
char ch;//the ch should be a array
main(){
  clrscr();
  printf("Enter a string: ");
  scanf("%s",&ch);//the ch don't need '&'
  c = &ch;//the ch don't need '&'
  printer(c);
  getch();
}


void printer(char *c){
  int x;
  for(x=0;x<strlen(c);x++){
     putch(*c);
  }
}
```

Comment: no problem with scanf().As scanf require a format string and according format address of memory to store. So no problem with scanf